# Force Documentation in VS(2010)

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, visual-studio, documentation

I am simply searching how to obtain `errors/warning` for each function/member that isnt documented.

Im pretty sure I managed to do this on one of my projects, but cant find how to do it here on my workstation.

I have looked into the `project` props, the solution props, but cant find it.

I must have missed something, or maybe I could do this at home with an extension.

Or it could also be because i am currently working on a VB.Net project, and not a C# project. 
Behavior changes considerably between `C#` and `VB`.

And google isnt helping me out too much ...

[image]

Edit : A small screenshot, in French, sorry about that. So some translation : 
"Compiler" is the Build Tab
Avertissements = Warning

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible for VB.NET projects.

[StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/), a code analyzer that integrates with Visual Studio, is capable to detecting missing documentation, as well as very many unrelated things. You'll have to configure the settings yourself to keep only the necessary rules on. The project's .chm contains all of the rules; `SA1600` is the rule you're looking for, but there may be other handy ones.

You can also use [Sandcastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) to find missing documentation by looking through outputted errors when building documentation.

Comment: Ok, so i'll have to use an extension to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for VB.NET, but in C# projects whenever you enable "XML documentation file" checkbox in project properties (Build tab), Visual Studio starts complaining on each undocumented public member and type.

Comment: Yeah, well that box is ticked. I think the behavior is just different, depending on  the language ... I really cant understand why they do such things...