# Is there an equivalent vor CS1591 (Missing XML comment) in visual Basic.NET?

Tags: vb.net, xml-comments

I have got a VB Project with the option "Generate XML Documentation" activated. Although some public Types and members don't have a comment, there is no warning at all, unlike in my C# projects.

Do I have to enable/disable anything, or is there no such warning in VB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Documentation in VS(2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684212/force-documentation-in-vs2010)

Comment: That's right. According to this, the simple answer is "no". So I'd have to use a third-party tool. I don't understand why they do this...