# How to force documentation in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, documentation

Back when I used to use Java and Eclipse, creating a new method would automatically add a Javadoc comment at the top of it. This resulted in me documenting a lot more than I currently do.

When using IntelliJ for Scala development I don't get the same feature, this makes the amount of documentation I write ending up quite small. Is there some way to add this feature to IntelliJ? If not, is there something similar I can do such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9684212/7390197) for Visual Studio (warning when there is no documentation found).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is supported, but you need to ask for the Scaladoc block (also known as a "docblock") to be generated. For example, given the following case class:

```
case class Wallet(password: String, destinationDirectory: File, isFullWallet: Boolean=true)
```

You can cause the docblock to be generated by typing `/**` on the line above the case class, and pressing Enter. You should now see:

```
/**
  * 
  * @param password
  * @param destinationDirectory
  * @param isFullWallet
  */
case class Wallet(password: String, destinationDirectory: File, isFullWallet: Boolean=true)
```

Now you can complete the documentation.

Comment: I know about this, but there a way to make this automatically happen without typing `/**`?

Comment: I do not think so

Comment: Would it be possible to create a plugin for a purpose?